# For a collection $S$ of weighted sets $S_i$, find those $k$ elements that maximise the sum of weights of all sets $S_i$ covered by them

Tags: algorithms, sets

I have a collection $S$ of sets $S_i$. Each $S_i$ has a weight given by how many times this set was observed in some data. I now want to find the $k$ elements that maximize the cumulative weight of all sets that can be covered by those elements (that is, those sets that contain only elements from those $k$ selected).

As an example, let $S$ consist of the following sets and corresponding weights:
$$  
\{1\} = 20  \\
\{2\} = 10  \\
\{3\} = 5  \\
\{1,2\} = 10  \\
\{2,3\} = 40  \\
\{1,3\} = 5  \\
\{1,2,3\} = 5\\
$$

In this case, I want my solution for $k = 2$ to be $\{2,3\}$, as $\{1,2\}$ has a cumulative weight of $20+10+10=40$, $\{1,3\}$ has a cumulative weight of $20+5+5=30$ and $\{2,3\}$ has a cumulative weight of $10+5+40=55$.

I have the feeling that my problem resembles a maximum coverage problem, but with a limit on the elements, not the sets, and with the sets having weights instead of the elements.

Comment: See if this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136561/is-minimum-coverage-problem-np-hard.

Comment: This minimum k-union problem seems to go in the right direction, but it tries to find $k$ of $n$ sets such that the number of elements in their union is minimal, while I try to find $k$ elements such that sum of weights for all of the original $n$ sets which are covered by those elements is maximal.

Comment: Perhaps you can relate the two problems.